# How to read *.adf files into R?

Tags: raster, data, r, esri-grid-format

I want to load .adf files into R. The data is from this page:
http://www.fao.org/geonetwork/srv/en/metadata.show?id=14057

I tried the following code that I found after some research in the internet. 
The problem is, that in the class RasterLayer I get negativ values that shouldn't be there. I don't know why this happens, so hopefully someone can help me!?

Code:

```
library(rgdal)
library(RColorBrewer)
dpath<- path...

x <- new("GDALReadOnlyDataset", dpath)
getDriver(x)
getDriverLongName(getDriver(x))
xx<-asSGDF_GROD(x)
r <- raster(xx)
```

The output for 'r' is:

> r
>   class       : RasterLayer
>   dimensions  : 2160, 4320, 9331200  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
>   resolution  : 0.08333333, 0.08333333  (x, y)
>   extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
>   coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs 
>   data source : in memory
>   names       : band1 
>   values      : -997, 16  (min, max)

The '16' in the values refers to the 16 classes of length of growing period. But I wonder where those '-997' come from. Maybe something wrong with the coord. ref?

Here is also a data summary of 'xx':

Data summary:
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
   -997       3       5      -9       8      16 7123158

And if we look at the data in xx more closely:

> table(xx$band1)

-997      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9     10     11     12 
 31711 429643  83011 166674 207228 270161 240958 183342 118608  98795  88473  73743  56022 
    13     14     15     16 
 30104  45521  52216  31832

There is really just this '-997' thing in it. I think the NAs are ozeans, so is there something wrong with the data loading or do I just don't understand the data?

Comment: Please change the title to something intelligent and accurate.

Comment: fwiw, there's no need to use rgdal directly at all, just raster(dpath)

Answer (score 4):

You are almost right:

NODATA is set to -32768 for oceans. Additionally, -997 is set for great lakes that are not excluded by the coastline.

Since the pixel content (growing period) makes no sense on lakes, you can safely treat -997 as NODATA too.